# Unable to maintain Session in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5, campaign-monitor

I'm using Laravel 5.3 and facing problems regarding the session which is not being preserved when I hit the URL with query string(UTM Querystring). It works fine without querystring and maintains the session.

1. mywebsite.com/booking (Works fine)
2. mywebsite.com/booking?utm_source=affiliate&utm_medium=mailer&utm_campaign=Ad2click (Destroys session as well cookies)

Wondering, what could be the reason?

```
public function bookProduct(Request $request){
    $zone = $request->zone;

    $records = Zone::where('zone_name',$zone)->get();

    foreach($records as $record){
        $zone_id = $record->id;
    }

    if ( Session::get('LAST_ACTIVITY') && (time() - Session::get('LAST_ACTIVITY') > 1200 )){

        echo 'expired';

    }

    else{

        $CheckOTP = Session::get('otp');

        /* Check if User Entered OTP Matches System Generated OTP */

        if ( $CheckOTP == $request->get_otp ) {

            /* Create new Customer */

            $recordCount = Customer::where('email', $request->customer_email)->orWhere('contact_number',$request->customer_contact_no)->count();

            if( $recordCount > 0 ){

                Customer::where('contact_number', $request->customer_contact_no)->update(['door_number' => $request->customer_pickup_door_no, 'building_name' => $request->customer_pickup_building_name, 'street_name' => $request->customer_pickup_street_name, 'area' => $request->customer_pickup_area, 'landmark' => $request->customer_pickup_landmark, 'pincode' => $request->customer_pickup_pincode, 'city'=>$request->customer_city]);
            }

            if($recordCount == 0 || $recordCount == ""){

                $customer = new Customer;

                $alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890';

                $pass = array(); //remember to declare $pass as an array

                $alphaLength = strlen($alphabet) - 1; //put the length -1 in cache

                for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {

                    $n = rand(0, $alphaLength);

                    $pass[] = $alphabet[$n];

                }

                $randomPass = implode($pass);

                $password = Hash::make('a');

                $customer->customer_name = $request->customer_name;

                $customer->email = $request->customer_email;

                $customer->contact_number = $request->customer_contact_no;

                $customer->password = $password;

                $customer->door_number = $request->customer_pickup_door_no;

                //$customer->street_name = $request->customer_pickup_street_name;

                //$customer->building_name = $request->customer_pickup_building_name;

                $customer->area = $request->customer_pickup_area;

                $customer->landmark = $request->customer_pickup_landmark;

                $customer->pincode = $request->customer_pickup_pincode;

                $customer->city = $request->customer_city;

                $customer->save();

                $id = $customer->id;

                $measurement = new Measurement;

                $measurement->customer_id = $id;

                $address = $request->customer_pickup_door_no .",".$request->customer_pickup_area .",".$request->customer_pickup_landmark .",". $request->customer_city.",". $request->customer_pickup_pincode;

                $measurement->save();

                $datas =    $this->create_customer($request->customer_contact_no,$request->customer_name, $request->customer_email,$address,$request->customer_pickup_pincode);

                $this->save_customers($request->customer_contact_no);

            }

            else{

            $address = $request->customer_pickup_door_no .",".$request->customer_pickup_area .",".$request->customer_pickup_landmark .",". $request->customer_city.",". $request->customer_pickup_pincode;

                 $datas =   $this->create_customer($request->customer_contact_no,$request->customer_name, $request->customer_email,$address,$request->customer_pickup_pincode);
                 $this->save_customers($request->customer_contact_no);

                    $fetchCustomer = Customer::where('email', $request->customer_email)->orWhere('contact_number',$request->customer_contact_no)->get();

                    foreach( $fetchCustomer as $customerId ){

                        $id = $customerId->id;

                    }

            }


            /* Store New Booking */

            /* Pickup address same as shipping address*/

            if( $request->duplicate_address == 'on'){

                $request->customer_shipping_door_no = $request->customer_pickup_door_no;

                //$request->customer_shipping_street_name = $request->customer_pickup_street_name;

                //$request->customer_shipping_building_name = $request->customer_pickup_building_name;

                $request->customer_shipping_area = $request->customer_pickup_area;

                $request->customer_shipping_landmark = $request->customer_pickup_landmark;

                $request->customer_shipping_pincode = $request->customer_pickup_pincode;
            }

            $booking = new Booking;

            $booking->customer_id = $id;

            $booking->look_id = Session::get("lookIds");

            $booking->time_slot_id = $request->slot;

            $booking->booking_date = strtr($request->booking_date, '/', '-');

            $booking->booking_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($booking->booking_date));

            $booking->door_number = $request->customer_shipping_door_no;

            //$booking->street_name = $request->customer_shipping_street_name;

            //$booking->building_name = $request->customer_shipping_building_name;

            $booking->landmark = $request->customer_shipping_landmark;

            $booking->pincode = $request->customer_shipping_pincode;

            $booking->city = $request->customer_city;

            $booking->area = $request->customer_shipping_area;

            $booking->fabric_availability = $request->fabric_material;

            $booking->otp = $CheckOTP;

            $booking->http_user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

            $zones = Zone::where('zone_name',$request->zone)->get();

            foreach( $zones as $zone){

                $booking->zone_id = $zone->id;
            }

            /* Fetch Latitude & Longitude from address */

            //$address = $request->customer_pickup_door_no.' ,'.$request->customer_pickup_street_name.' ,'.$request->customer_pickup_building_name.' ,'.$request->customer_pickup_landmark;

            $address = $request->customer_pickup_door_no.' ,'.$request->customer_pickup_landmark.' ,'.$request->customer_shipping_area;

            $prepAddr = str_replace(' ','+',$address);

            $geocode = file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$prepAddr.'&sensor=false');

            $output= json_decode($geocode);


            if( $output->status != "ZERO_RESULTS" ){

                $latitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;

                $longitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

            }
            else{

                $booking->latitude = "";

                $booking->longitude = "";
            }

            $lastId = Booking::max('id');

            $lastId = $lastId+1;

            $booking->booking_id = 'BK'.date("ymd").str_pad($lastId, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); 

            $checkCouponApply = $request->check_coupon_apply;

            if($checkCouponApply == '1'){

                $couponCode = $request->discount_coupon;

                $booking->coupon_code = $request->discount_coupon;

                $getDiscountPercentage = Discount::where('coupon_code',$couponCode)->pluck('coupon_percentage');

                $getDiscountPercentage = $getDiscountPercentage[0];

                Discount::where('coupon_code',$booking->coupon_code)->decrement('remaining_user_count');


            }

            $booking->save();

            Session::set('bookingId', $booking->id);

            if($request->trouser > 0 && $request->shirt > 0){

                Session::set('productBought', 'Shirt & Trouser');

            }
            else if($request->trouser>0){

                Session::set('productBought', 'Trouser');

            }

            else if($request->shirt>0){

                Session::set('productBought', 'Shirt');

            }

            /* Store products data for Booking */



            $trouserRecord = Categories::where('category_name','Trouser')->pluck('id');

            $shirtRecord = Categories::where('category_name','Shirt')->pluck('id');

            $trouserPrice = ProductPrice::where('zone_id',$zone_id)
                                        ->where('category_id',$trouserRecord[0])
                                        ->pluck('price');

            $shirtPrice = ProductPrice::where('zone_id',$zone_id)
                                        ->where('category_id',$shirtRecord[0])
                                        ->pluck('price');


            $shirtUnitPrice = $shirtPrice[0];

            $trouserUnitPrice = $trouserPrice[0];


            $products = array('trouser' => array('count' => $request->trouser, 'category' => $trouserRecord[0], 'price'=>$trouserPrice[0], 'unit_price'=>$trouserUnitPrice), 'shirt' => array('count' => $request->shirt, 'category' => $shirtRecord[0], 'price'=>$shirtPrice[0], 'unit_price'=>$shirtUnitPrice));

            foreach($products as $product){

                for($i=0;$i<$product['count'];$i++){

                    $subBooking = new SubBooking;

                    //Calculate tax tmount for each lined up product and save relavant data

                    $subBooking->booking_id = $booking->id;

                    if($product['category'] == '3'){

                        $subBooking->category_name = 'Shirt';

                    }
                    else if($product['category'] == '4'){

                        $subBooking->category_name = 'Trouser';

                    }

                    $setTaxes = Tax::all();

                    foreach($setTaxes as $taxes){

                        $tax[$taxes->tax_type] = $product['unit_price']*($taxes->percentage/100);

                        $tax[$taxes->tax_type.'Percentage'] = $taxes->percentage;

                    }

                    $subBooking->service_tax = $tax['Service Tax'];

                    $subBooking->service_tax_percentage = $tax['Service TaxPercentage'];

                    $subBooking->swachh_bharat = $tax['Swachh Bharat'];

                    $subBooking->swachh_bharat_percentage = $tax['Swachh BharatPercentage'];

                    $subBooking->krishi_kalyan = $tax['Krishi Kalyan'];

                    $subBooking->krishi_kalyan_percentage = $tax['Krishi KalyanPercentage'];

                    $subBooking->category_id = $product['category'];

                    $subBooking->unit_price = $product['unit_price'];

                    $subBooking->unit_price = $product['unit_price'];

                    $subBooking->quantity = 1;

                    $subBooking->save();

                }


            }

            if($subBooking){

                    $this->storeReportingData('new');

            }

            $email = $request->customer_email;
            $booking_date_new = date("d M Y", strtotime($booking->booking_date));

            $time_slot_data = TimeSlot::where('id',$booking->time_slot_id)->first();
            $start = date("g:i a", strtotime($time_slot_data['start'])); 
            $end = date("g:i a", strtotime($time_slot_data['end'])); 

            $msg = "Thank you for booking with us. Your booking ref number is: $booking->booking_id and our appointment with you is on $booking_date_new ($start - $end).";  

            $action = 'New Booking';

            $description = "Booking has been created";

            $this->saveLog($booking->id, $action, $description);

            Session::forget('lookIds');

            $contact_no = $request->customer_contact_no;;

            $urlapi              = "https://api-in.bsmart.in/api/v3/sendsms/plain?";

            $user                = "USER";

            $password            = "SECRET";

            $senderid            = "SENDER_ID";

            $pin = mt_rand(1000, 9999);

            $msg_order_confirmation = urlencode("$msg");

            $msg2 = "Dear Customer, Please spare 45 minutes of your valuable time with our stylists for a perfect styling experience.";

            $sms_url = $urlapi."User=".$user."&Password=".$password."&Sender=".$senderid."&GSM=91".$contact_no."&SMSText=".$msg_order_confirmation;

            // Initialize session and set URL.
            $ch = curl_init();

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sms_url);

            // Set so curl_exec returns the result instead of outputting it.
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

            // Get the response and close the channel.

            $response = curl_exec($ch);

            curl_close($ch);

            $email_message = $msg." ".$msg2;
            //$this->sendEmail($email,$email_message);  
            $this->sendSMS($contact_no,$msg2);

            $sub_bookings = SubBooking::where('booking_id',$booking->id)->where('quantity','<>', 0)->get();

            $data = array();

            foreach($sub_bookings as $sub_booking){

                $quantity = $sub_booking->quantity;

                $category_data = Categories::where('id',$sub_booking->category_id)->first();
                $category_name = $category_data['category_name']; 

                $data[] = array('quantity'=>$quantity,'category_name'=>$category_name);  
            }  

            $appointment_date = date("d M Y", strtotime($booking->booking_date));

            $time_slot_data = TimeSlot::where('id',$booking->time_slot_id)->first();
            $start = date("g:i a", strtotime($time_slot_data['start'])); 
            $end = date("g:i a", strtotime($time_slot_data['end'])); 

            $customer_data = Customer::where('id',$booking->customer_id)->first();
            $customer_name = $customer_data['customer_name'];

            $email_data = array('email'=>$email,'customer_name'=>$customer_name,'from'=>'notifications-noreply@raymondcustomtailoring.com','from_name'=>'Raymond','appointment_date'=>$appointment_date,'appointment_id'=>$booking->booking_id,'customer_name'=>$customer_name,'address'=>$address,'pincode'=>$request->customer_shipping_pincode,'data'=>$data,'start'=>$start,'end'=>$end);

            /*Mail::send(['html'=>'confirm'],$email_data, function( $message ) use ($email_data)
            {
                $message->to( $email_data['email'] )->from($email_data['from'],$email_data['from_name'] )->subject($email_data['appointment_id'].' Appointment Confirmed');

            });*/
            //return $booking->id;

        }

        else{

            echo 'mismatched';

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe you`re not describe the real problem.Edit with more details and code.

Comment: This is a weird interaction. Can you share your controller logic for this route?

Comment: @Mihai logged in user is getting logged out when I hit this url mywebsite.com/booking?utm_source=affiliate&utm_medium=mailer&utm_campaign=Ad2click. The url leads to the booking form, while submitting I put some values in session but it destroys all session once form submitted.

Comment: @Sandeesh Session::set('bookingId', $booking->id);

       if($request->trouser > 0 && $request->shirt > 0){

        Session::set('productBought', 'Shirt & Trouser');

       }
       else if($request->trouser>0){

        Session::set('productBought', 'Trouser');

       }

       else if($request->shirt>0){

        Session::set('productBought', 'Shirt');

       }

Comment: I can't seem to find anything that might cause this issue. Word of advice, don't use echo in your controller logic. Always use returns. You can debug your controller method step by step to check where the session is getting invalidated. Try running a dd(session()->all()) inside your controller at different points and verify the session data.